# Two Tables with Similar but Different Column Elements - Looking to Merge

Tags: r

I am on a project to make some of my company's databases more relational by implementing identical variables in related columns between the two tables.  My sample data looks like this (my actual data has a lot more values):

```
A               B
Farm Date   FARM DATE
Dog Numbers DOG NUM
Cat Numbers CAT NUM
Pig Count   PIG CNT
Cow Numbers COW NUM
Grass       GRASS
Hay         HAY 
Feed        FEED
Corn        CORN
Crops       CROPS
Price       WEEK
Time        MONTH
Date        FARMER
            PEANUTS
            VEGGIES
            BARN TYPE
```

So, Column B contains more items than Column A, which is fine.  I'm not trying to just match up the common items.  I'm trying to generate a column that contains all of the common items **and the items that aren't common to both columns.**

Could `tidyr` be used to accomplish this?  Any help to accomplish this is appreciated!

Hoped outcome:

```
C
Farm Date   
Dog Numbers 
Cat Numbers 
Pig Count   
Cow Numbers 
Grass      
Hay      
Feed      
Corn        
Crops       
Price    
Time   
Date    
Farmer
Peanuts
Veggies
Barn Type
```

Comment: Can you show your expected output based on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `union` function.
Example:

```
A<-c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
B<-c("d", "b", "e", "f", "g")

union(A, B)
# [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g"
```

To make the strings comparable you can use the `tolower()` before you apply `union`.

Comment: Thanks guys.  Question - does `union` remove duplicates in the two columns?  (Assuming they are the same case and text).